# Java application integration with a server and Rails?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jsp, servlets, server

I have just finished production of a java application that scrapes a website, takes information such as prices and names from it, and sorts the data. The data is then stored in a server. A colleague is then going to use ruby on rails to extract the information from the server that my application has stored, and display it to the user. In this case, what would be the most useful tool to place my application server-side and make it continuously running? Would JSP or the use of a servlet be the solution? Sorry for the noob question, my background is OOP and this is my first web-based project. Thanks for any help!
EDIT: The server is an amazon web server which uses a PostGreSQL database.

Comment: return a json or xml document to "ruby-on-rails" app. It should format and display data.  (Your question is  offtopic on SO, though)

Comment: Expose the data via Rest, then anything can access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks some information.

Who is the "server"?

- Is it just a machine connected to the web and you stored data files on its hard-drive?
- Is it a daemon running on a machine, such as database servers or ftp server?

How do you store the data on server?

- If it's files on a machine I can suggest using Apache web server on that machine to gain access to resources on your "server machine".
   Another idea is installing an ftp server on your machine. It will grant access to a declared part of the machine's file system.
- If it's a database (whether SQL or No-SQL), all databases have the server side program that runs as a daemon and is accessible with database connectors through the machine's IP address and the port the DB uses.
- Another option is, as you mentioned, using an active web server, such as Apache's Tomcat. This way you can run a web application  (html/jsp that use your java project)  which will provide an easier access to the data for your colleague. For example, the web app can extract the needed data and export it as json or xml or plain text.

Then your colleague will have the ability to access your stored data with his web-application written in ruby.

Comment: The server is a web server hosted on an amazon server. We are using a PostGreSQL database.

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL, you should have a link, a username and a password through which you can connect to it. Your colleague's ruby application should connect through it.
Try amazon's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html)